# Get most similar words using GloVe

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I am new to GloVe. I successfully ran their [demo.sh](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe) as given in their website. After running demo I got several files created such as `vocab`, `vectors` etc. But they haven't any documentation or anything that describes what files we need to use and how to use to find most similar words.

Hence, please help me to find the most similar words given a word in GloVe (using cosine similarity)? (e.g., like `most.similar` in Gensim word2vec)

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter how word vectors are generated, you can always calculate cosine similarity between the words. The easiest way to achieve what you asked for is (considering you have gensim):

```
python -m gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec –input <GloVe vector file> –output <Word2vec vector file>
```

This will convert glove vector file to w2v format. You can do it manually too - just add extra line to your GloVe file containing total number of vectors and their dimensionality at the top of your file. It looks something a kin of:

```
180000 300
<The rest of your file>
```

After that you can just load the file into gensim and everything is working as if it is a regular w2v model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer. I tried to edit the demo.sh and use it for my text file. However, I get an error saying `28987 Segmentation fault: 11  $BUILDDIR/glove -save-file $SAVE_FILE -input-file $COOCCURRENCE_SHUF_FILE -iter $MAX_ITER -vector-size $VECTOR_SIZE -vocab-file $VOCAB_FILE` can you please let me know why this happens?

Comment: or can you please tell me a consistent way to build my own GloVe models?